# c# using a generic method with a type known at runtime for asynchronous method

Tags: c#, rest, generics, async-await, runtime

I'm trying to do a rest api call where I want to read into an object known at runtime. Code is simplified for example.

```
object o = null;
if (True)  //condition irrelevant just to indicate selection control
    o = new List<Product>();
else
    o = new Product();

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
 o = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<o.GetType()>();
```

o.GetType() isn't the right approach.  Is there something I can do that can determine the correct generic type at runtime for this?

Comment: Is the number of possibilities limited to 2 options ?

Comment: You can build the generic call via reflection at runtime, but really you should put the response/read inside the `if` statement and have two different ones. I'm not sure why you are `new`ing them, the ReadAsAsync just overwrites it with whatever type you use for the generic...

Answer (score 1):

```
o = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync(o.GetType())
```

see [HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontentextensions.readasasync(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync%28System.Net.Http.HttpContent,System.Type%29)